# how to create a updatable coreml model?

Tags: coreml

I tried to build a pre-trained core-ml model with the help of create ML framework, but the model created is not updatable, Is there a way to create a pre-trained core-ml model which can be updated on the device itself (newly introduced feature in Core-ML 3) ?

Answer (score 5):

Not directly with Create ML, you'll have to use coremltools to make the model updatable. See here for examples: https://github.com/apple/coremltools/tree/main/examples

However... this will only work for neural networks and k-nearest neighbors models. Create ML does not actually produce these kinds of models (at the moment).

For example, an image classifier trained with Create ML is a GLM on top of a fixed neural network. You cannot make GLM models updatable at this point.

So in short, no, you can't make models trained with Create ML updatable.

Comment: I am currently using Xcode 10.3 10G8 version, and i tried to run the following method it is giving error
"validator error: The .mlmodel supplied is of version 4, intended for a newer version of Xcode. This version of Xcode supports model version 3 or earlier."

Comment: yes and what about updatable coreml image classifiers

Comment: What about them?

Comment: well create ML can create image classifiers, so as in the jupyter notebooks of the solution mentioned above don't show anything about an image classifier, is it possible to create an updatable core ML image classifier

Comment: Yes. The MNIST example from that folder is an updatable image classifier.